# Why does typing a variable (or expression) print the value to stdout?

Tags: python, ipython, read-eval-print-loop, python-interactive

Take this example:

```
>>> 5+10
15
>>> a = 5 + 10
>>> a
15
```

How and why does Python do this without an explicit print statement?

If I do the same thing in an [IPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) cell, only the last such value is actually printed on stdout in this way:

```
In[1]: 5+10
       1

Out[1]: 1
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When Python is in "interactive" mode, it enables certain behaviors it doesn't have in non-interactive mode. For example, [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook), originally specified in [PEP 217](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0217/).

> If value is not None, this function prints it to sys.stdout, and saves it in `__builtin__._`.
>
> sys.displayhook is called on the result of evaluating an expression entered in an interactive Python session.

You can modify this behavior:

```
>>> import sys
>>> def shook(expr):
...   print(f'can haz {expr}?')
...
>>> sys.displayhook = shook
>>> 123
can haz 123?
>>> False
can haz False?
>>> None
can haz None?
```

And also set it back to normal:

```
>>> sys.displayhook = sys.__displayhook__
>>> 3
3
```

In the default Python repl, `sys.displayhook` is

```
>>> import sys;
>>> sys.displayhook
<built-in function displayhook>
```

but in IPython it's

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.displayhook
Out[2]: <IPython.terminal.prompts.RichPromptDisplayHook at 0x7f630717fa58>
```

So that's why you see different behavior between Python and IPython.

Answer (score 2):

That's how all interpreters work. They don't need any `print`, but one thing, and without `print` they do the `repr` of everything, and `print` doesn't, example:

```
>>> 'blah'
'blah'
>>> print('blah')
blah
>>>
```

Look at the quotes.

Also see this:

```
>>> print(repr('blah'))
'blah'
>>>
```

`repr` does the same.

Comment: any comment on the IPython behavior?

Comment: Let's say CPython in interactive mode works like that.